# pyspark---randomForests specify categorical variables using "categoricalFeaturesInfo"

Tags: apache-spark, categories, random-forest, decision-tree, pyspark

how do you specify categoricalFeaturesInfo in pyspark randomForests?

the documentation isn't very clear on this and I tried a few like:

categoricalFeaturesInfo= {(12,4)}

categoricalFeaturesInfo= {(12->4)}

categoricalFeaturesInfo= {Map[int,int](12,4)}

... etc and none of them work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

From the python documentation we have:

```
categoricalFeaturesInfo: Map storing arity of categorical
             features.  E.g., an entry (n -> k) indicates that
             feature n is categorical with k categories indexed
             from 0: {0, 1, ..., k-1}.
```

Try using:

```
categoricalFeaturesInfo = {12:4}
```

Comment: categoricalFeaturesInfo = {12:4}: Not working either

Comment: My bad, I forgot python index starts with 0 here... so categoricalFeaturesInfo = {11:4} works

Comment: What about using a `months` variable, with categories from 1 to 12? If `months` is the first column: `categoricalFeaturesInfo = {0:12}` will not work, as it will look for categories between 0 and 11!

Answer (score 0):

For spark 2.0 and above

Its a Dictionary 
with key as index/position of variable in rdd(feature)
and value as number of categories